# Differential Equations!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem:

Find the solution of the differential equation $dy/dx = x/y$ that satisfies the initial condition $y(0) = −7$.

I ended up getting $y = \sqrt{x^2 + 2C}$

I solved for $C$ by plugging in my initial values given, $0$ and $-7$.

Got $C =  49/2$

plugged $C$ back in with a final answer as:

$y = \sqrt{x^2 + 49}$

The above answer is wrong and I'm not sure why! Please help : )

Comment: $y^2=x^2+c\implies y=\pm \sqrt{x^2+c}.$ Maybe you should consider $y=-\sqrt.$

Comment: $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac xy \to  y\,dy = x\,dx \to \int y\,dy = \int x\,dx \to \frac 12 y^2 = \frac 12 x^2 + C \iff y^2 = x^2 + c \iff y = \pm\sqrt{x^2+c}$$  If $y(0) = -7$, then we have that $-7= \pm\sqrt{0+c} \implies -7 = -(\sqrt{49})$, i.e. The solution being $y = -\sqrt{x^2 + 49}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ydy=xdx\implies y^2=x^2+C$$

$$\implies y=\pm\sqrt{x^2+C}$$

$$y(0)=-7\implies y=-\sqrt{x^2+49}$$